# ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt' using anaconda python windows

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-x, rasa-sdk

I am trying to install the dependencies in a python3 virtual environment.
**pip install -r requirements.txt**
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Err no 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

I have to install development dependencies for building the chatbot using RASA 3.0.
I have created a virtual environment in anaconda and am not able to install the dependency. Help me out

Comment: Please show the list of files in the directory because it's showing that file is missing

Comment: admin@DESKTOP-ANU0UOB MINGW64 ~/IThelpdesk/helpdesk-assistant (main)
$ dir
Dockerfile.chatroom    congress           rasa.db
LICENSE                data               requirements-dev.txt
Makefile               domain.yml         requirements.txt
README.md              endpoints.yml      screenshots
actions                format_results.py  source
chatroom_handoff.html  handoff.gif        tests
config.yml             pyproject.toml

Comment: looks like the file is present in your directory. Check again. It must be a small mistake. You can try with the absolute path also:-  pip install  -r ~/IThelpdesk/helpdesk-assistant/requirements.txt